# How can I find the sum of this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The series is 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{3k}{k!}x^{3k-1}$$
I already calculated 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3k}}{k!}=e^{x^3}$$
So I tried to make the two look similar but I don't know what to do with the extra $k$ in the first series. It could cancel with the factorial but then it would look even less like the second series?

Comment: Differentiate.$ $

Comment: take that same idea, but then note that $x^{3k-1}=x^{3(k-1)}\cdot x^2$

Comment: @brent I was thinking the same thing.. That way we can have $k-1$ instead of $k$

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of the series you calculated. The answer is $3x^2 e^{x^3}$.

Comment: Well, that was an unfair downvote!

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for the downvote, there is a [chatroom explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649).

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3k}}{k!} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^{3k}}{k!} $$
$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d}{dx}x^{3k} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{3k}{k!}x^{3k-1} $$
Therefore
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{3k}{k!}x^{3k-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3k}}{k!}$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^3}=3x^2e^{x^3} $$